How to print CN,issuer and dates of PEM certificate chain
I want to to print the CN,issuer and dates of a certificate chain containing one certificate and the intermediate certificate :
$ grep -c BEGIN.CERTIFICATE myCert.pem
2
$

So I tried this :
$ openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile myCert.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs | openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer -dates
subject=CN = *.myDomain.com
issuer=C = FR, O = Gandi, CN = Gandi Standard SSL CA 2
notBefore=May  4 00:00:00 2023 GMT
notAfter=Jun  1 23:59:59 2024 GMT
$

But I only get the information for the first certificate.
How do I do this ?

(0) not programming or development (1) openssl x509 processes exactly one cert not more (2) openssl crl2pkcs7 ... | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text | grep -E 'Issuer:|Subject:|Not Before:|Not After :' | sed 's/^ *//' (but note this may not preserve the order of the input if that matters to you) OR on Unix or Unixy shell only while openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer -dates 2>/dev/null; do :; done <certs.pem

crossdupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696224/using-openssl-to-display-all-certificates-of-a-pem-file https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366898/generate-hpkp-fingerprints-for-all-certificate-chain https://serverfault.com/questions/391396/how-to-split-a-pem-file https://serverfault.com/questions/590870/how-to-view-all-ssl-certificates-in-a-bundle (where it is ontopic)
